# MySQL 1062 duplicate key

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, amazon-aurora

Facing the following issue:

```
(1062, "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'")
```

This is my table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `expired_tokens` (
`expired_tokens_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`token` varchar(255)
DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`expired_tokens_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `expired_tokens_id_UNIQUE` (`expired_tokens_id`)
)
```

I'm facing this issue after a db migration in 5.7 to AWS Aurora if that is helpful in anyway. I've truncated the table already and after the first value gets inserted to this table I face the 1062.

Any help appreciated!

Edit:
Stored procedure being called that throws the error:

```
user_login(IN jti_token varchar(255),IN u_id varchar(255))
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT isnull(active_token) 
        FROM users  
        WHERE user_id = u_id
        ) 
    THEN
        UPDATE users 
            SET last_login = now(), 
                active_token = jti_token 
        WHERE user_id = u_id;
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO expired_tokens  
                (expired_tokens_id, token) 
        VALUES (default, 
                (SELECT active_token 
                 FROM users 
                 WHERE user_id = u_id
                )
            );
        UPDATE users 
            SET last_login = now(), 
                active_token = jti_token 
        WHERE user_id = u_id;
```

Comment: What does the query throwing the error look like?

Comment: It's a stored procedure

Comment: Are you sure this is from the insert into `expired_tokens` and not the update of `users`? It doesn't look like this should be an issue on `expired_tokens` from the SQLs you provided. As far as I know the `AUTO_INCREMENT` starts with `1`, not `0` and the error seems to suggest you're trying to insert another `0`. Have you tried to log the `jti_token` and `u_id` and then run the individual SQLs from the procedure manually to see which of them causes the error? (Low level debugging, I know. But can be quite useful :-)

Comment: @Scratte somehow the SP keeps inserting into expired_tokens with id of 0 for the primary key instead of auto incrementing

Comment: I'm sorry. I do not know what an SP is. If you meant "Stored Procedure" kindly just type such things out. Guessing what abbreviations are is time consuming and not very productive. Have you checked the stored procedure and the table definition after the migration to be sure that it's consistent with the old? The procedure isn't inserting `0`. It's using `default`.

Comment: I think you can just remove `expired_tokens_id` from the insert entirely if you're not assigning it a particular value (which you're not, since `default` isn't particular).